# Destructor being called more than expected

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code where new is not used, but std::move() is called.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

class Animal {
public:
    Animal() { std::cout << "Animal()" << std::endl; };
    ~Animal() { std::cout << "~Animal()" << std::endl; };
    virtual void eat() { std::cout << "Animal is eating" << std::endl; };
};

class Bear : public Animal {
public:
    Bear() { std::cout << "Bear()" << std::endl; };
    ~Bear() { std::cout << "~Bear()" << std::endl; };
    void eat() { std::cout << "Bear is eating" << std::endl; };
};

class Zebra : public Animal {
public:
    Zebra() { std::cout << "Zebra()" << std::endl; };
    ~Zebra() { std::cout << "~Zebra()" << std::endl; };
    void eat() { std::cout << "Zebra is eating" << std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
    Bear bear;
    Zebra zebra;

    std::vector<Animal*> animalsp;
    animalsp.push_back(&bear);
    animalsp.push_back(&zebra);
    for (auto i : animalsp) {
        i->eat();
    }

    std::vector<Animal> animals;
    animals.push_back(std::move(bear));
    animals.push_back(std::move(zebra));
    for (auto i : animals) {
        i.eat();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Animal()
Bear()
Animal()
Zebra()
Bear is eating
Zebra is eating
~Animal()
Animal is eating
~Animal()
Animal is eating
~Animal()
~Animal()
~Animal()
~Zebra()
~Animal()
~Bear()
~Animal()
```

I would have expected fewer calls to the `~Animal()` destructor. I also find the timing of the calls to `~Animal()` to be unexpected. I would have expected the `std::move()` call to trigger this perhaps, but then to do so before the output of the function call. I get the same output on [ideone](https://ideone.com/NarEvm) and VS2015. What am I missing?

Comment: Your slicing objects in the second vector.

Comment: "I would have expected fewer calls to the ~Animal() destructor" -- Ok, what exactly do you expect to see?

Comment: Thank you everyone for great answers, especially Yakk and Dieter Lücking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move doesn't destroy objects, it just flags their state as being disposable.  So the move doesn't cause a destroy (unless the vector is reallocated by the push back!)

Automatic storage objects (declared as locals in a function, say) are destroyed at the end of their scope.  That is why you get all those destructors at the end.

When the vector is destroyed, it destroys the animals stored inside it (which are not Bears or Zebras, just animals, as you asked them to be stored by-value, and that means the Bear-ness got sliced off them).  This is another source of destructors.

The `for (auto i:animals)`  loop also creates a copy of each animal in the vector, which is destroyed.  Yet more destructor spam.

```
Animal()
Bear() // Bear bear; line
Animal()
Zebra() // Zebra zebra; line
Bear is eating
Zebra is eating // first loop
~Animal() // reallocation of vector during push_backs
Animal is eating // second loop body
~Animal() // first i copy destroyed in second loop
Animal is eating // second loop body
~Animal() // second i copy destroyed in second loop 
~Animal()
~Animal() // vector destroyed 
~Zebra()
~Animal() // zerbra destroyed
~Bear()
~Animal() // bear destroyed
```

In the event that something takes 2 lines, I commented the 2nd line.

Comment: What that means, is that you arw destryoing all of them at the end. Your programming logic is aloof on how many you created.

Comment: Aha, I was confused by the destructor after "Zebra is eating", I'd overlooked the vector resizing.

Comment: @MooingDuck [No one expects the vector reallocation.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WJXHY2OXGE)

Answer (score 2):

`for (auto i : animals)` is creating copies of the objects in the vector.  This could be the source of a lot of the destructor calls you see.  Usually it's preferred to pass by reference in this case, as in:

`for (auto& i : animals)`

Answer (score 1):

Even when using move semantics you have multiple objects which are destroyed at the end of there scope. The implementation of the move semantic is an internal implementation of these objects.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
class Resource
{
    public:
    int data =  0;
    Resource()
    {
        std::cout << "Allocate resource\n";
        data = 1;
    }

    Resource(Resource&& other)
    :   data(other.data)
    {
        std::cout << "Transfer resource\n";
        other.data = 0;
    }

    Resource& operator = (Resource&& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Transfer resource\n";
        data = other.data;
        other.data = 0;
        return *this;
    }

    Resource(const Resource&) = delete;
    Resource& operator = (const Resource&) = delete;

    ~Resource()
    {
        if(data)
            std::cout << "Deallocate resource\n";
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    Resource a;
    Resource b(std::move(a));
    return 0;
    // Destruction of a and b follows.
}
```

Note: Not the object holding data is the concern of move semantics, but the data itself.

Output:

```
Allocate resource
Transfer resource
Deallocate resource
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to misunderstand the actual mechanics of std::move and rvalue references. When you construct an object using an rvalue reference, the expected (but by no means contractual) behavior is that the receiving constructor will assume control over any dynamic memory that was held by the reference, then change the reference object to reflect the fact that it no longer has control over any of the dynamic memory.

This in no way means that the rvalue that was passed in will be discarded immediately. The destructor is still called regardless of whether or not it was moved. The key difference is that the destructor will be able to detect that the object had been moved, so there is no call to deallocate memory.

Granted, C++ is a very powerful language, and is thus subject to abuses. You can do whatever you want in an rvalue reference constructor or destructor. This is just the most common pattern as malloc and free are very expensive, so calling them as little as possible is good design.